# Object reference required for non-static field MVC5 Async

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, async-await

I am trying to populate a model and pass it to a View in MVC5 using an async service call, and am receiving the Object reference required.... error.  The call is with an ActionResult

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetDeptInfo(int deptId)        
{
 DepartmentModel deptModel = await PeopleLinkOperations.GetDepartmentProfile(deptId);
 return View("Details", deptModel);
}
```

GetDepartmentProfile is declared like this;

```
public async Task<DepartmentModel> GetDepartmentProfile(int deptId)
{
  //Operation to get all department and employee details, based on department ID
  List<EmployeesModel> employees = new List<EmployeesModel>();
  DepartmentModel dept = new DepartmentModel();
  List<DepartmentEscalateModel> escContacts = new List<DepartmentEscalateModel>();
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  Parameters @params = new Parameters();
  EmployeeService empService = new EmployeeService();
  //code to populate model pieces
  //call out to service to return a list of models to bind to the DepartmentModel
  var empInfo = await empService.GetEmployeeDetails(dr2["accountname"].ToString());

  return dept;
}

GetEmployeeDetails() declaration

public async Task<List<EmployeesModel>> GetEmployeeDetails(string account)
{
  //return employee details, works when called from other areas
}
```

That's really all it is i'd say, i'm not sure what part would be considered a static field that I am returning, I am new to the service calls and MVC in general.  Also, this will only ever return 1 record in the List from the GetEmployeeDetails(), other areas return a full list.
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: where do you intialize empService?

Comment: you need an instance of `PeopleLinkOperations`, you're trying to access it as if it were a static class.  The `async` part is irrelevant here.

Comment: empService is initialized in the GetDepartmentProfile() call and that DepartmentModel() declaration, i can include all of that, it's just that isn't the issue.  I have PeopleLinkOperations declared within this page to reference the services.